# Resources not visible (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have Xamarin. Android app and after I open project, I don't see any resources

[image]

I have no idea why so.

I make Clean and Rebuild

Maybe someone faced this problem? How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is bug of last Visual Studio 2017 build. On previous all okay

Comment: maybe something went wrong in the instalation, have you tried install again?

Comment: Nope . I just install VS 2015@CDrosos